# Python with Selenium Google Translate Error

Tags: python, selenium

I dont know where the problem is
I used theese sources
https://medium.com/python/python-selenium-mod%C3%BCl%C3%BC-kullan%C4%B1m%C4%B1-ders-1-36983185164c
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=olOswIyeRlY
*Code*

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys

import time
driver_path = r"C:\Users\ruzgaricatsirketi\Desktop\chromedriver_win32\chromedriver.exe"
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=driver_path)
driver.get("https://translate.google.com/#tr/tr")
dinle = driver.find_element_by_id('gt-speech')
dinle.click()
time.sleep(2)
dinle.click()
time.sleep(3)
getir = driver.find_element_by_id('result_box').text

print(getir)
```

**Error**

```
DevTools listening on ws://127.0.0.1:12239/devtools/browser/76eb55d7-8aef-4b19-9d6e-fda8f4f1aee4
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\ruzgaricatsirketi\Desktop\test.py", line 13, in <module>
    getir = driver.find_element_by_id('result_box').text
  File "C:\Users\ruzgaricatsirketi\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 360, in find_element_by_id
    return self.find_element(by=By.ID, value=id_)
  File "C:\Users\ruzgaricatsirketi\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 978, in find_element
    'value': value})['value']
  File "C:\Users\ruzgaricatsirketi\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 321, in execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)
  File "C:\Users\ruzgaricatsirketi\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\errorhandler.py", line 242, in check_response
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"id","selector":"result_box"}
  (Session info: chrome=78.0.3904.97)
  (Driver info: chromedriver=2.35.528161 (5b82f2d2aae0ca24b877009200ced9065a772e73),platform=Windows NT 10.0.18362 x86_64)
```

Comment: There is no element with id `result_box`. What are you trying to find?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to work with Python correctly, it is crucial to learn to read the stack trace. In your case, these lines

```
File "C:\Users\ruzgaricatsirketi\Desktop\test.py", line 13, in <module>
   getir = driver.find_element_by_id('result_box').text
```

say that the exception has its origin on line 13 in your file *test.py*, where you are trying to search for web element with *id* attribute set to value `"result_box"`. Exception you have got is *NoSuchElementException*:

```
selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"id","selector":"result_box"}
```

As you can find in [official documentation](https://selenium.dev/selenium/docs/api/py/common/selenium.common.exceptions.html#module-selenium.common.exceptions) or many other places (and I bet there are thousands of them), this exception is raised when the element you are searching for is not found.

Try it yourself — open your tested Google Translator page and try to search for element with any existing *id*. E.g. on line 8 in your test file you are trying to locate element with *id* `"gt-speech"`. Write `document.getElementById("gt-speech")` to your browsers console and whoala! It works, this node matches your search:

```
<div id="gt-speech" class="speech-button goog-toolbar-button"...>...</div>
```

Note especially the `id="gt-speech"` attribute, it is the one selenium will use to identify the object. However, if you try the same with *id* `"result_box"`, you will get nothing (`null` is returned if using JS console to search for element), because there is **no such element** on the page (thus **NoSuchElementException**...).

My advice for you:

- inspect the element you are trying to locate (on the most of the popular web browsers on Windows/Linux systems it is as easy as right-clicking the element and selecting the *inspect* option)
- select some unique properties, you can use also [other properties than id](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/locating-elements.html) (preferably not inner text; IDs are best, but they are not always present...)
- use those properties to find the element using selenium

And please, next time try to search a bit on your own before you ask, because this is some really really trivial problem you should be able to handle after first 5 minutes of any selenium course (in other words, UTFG :P)

**EDIT**

P.S. I can see you have got that invalid *id* from the video you have marked as your source. The fact that element with such *id* was present one year ago does not mean it will be there forever (an for every platform). If you need to get that certain element, you have to find another way how to define it using selenium locators I have mentioned earlier.